# DataKeyNames for different tables with different primary key names

Tags: c#, asp.net, primary-key, datakey

I'm wondering if there is a way to use datakeynames to access the primary keys of different tables if those primary key names are different in those tables.

For example, I have a table called Table1 and Table2 where the primary keys are Table1ID and Table2ID respectively.

My ultimate goal is to combine the contents of both tables into 1 gridview, and to generate a hyperlink for both every row. So my c# looks something like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("(SELECT Table1ID, Title FROM Table1" +
                                             "UNION ALL SELECT Table2ID, Title FROM Table2)", connection);

 GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Then in my Gridview_Databound method, I go through and set the hyperlinks for each row individually. The problem is how do I access Table1ID and Table2ID? In my .aspx code, can I set that to be a BoundField because the DataField won't be consistent? I can't just do the following because then it neglects Table2ID right?

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Table1ID"/>
```

Maybe I need to use a templateField or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templatefield as below code

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" ToolTip="Click to edit" CommandName="EditContent" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Table1ID") %>' />    
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now on your OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" you will get the pk id of this tables.

Comment: I see that it is only doing Eva("Table1ID"). How would this get the pk of Table 2 then?

Comment: change your query as below

SELECT Table1ID, Title FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Table2ID AS Table1ID, Title FROM Table2

Comment: Awesome! I didn't use the templatefield but knowing that I could do the SELECT Table2ID AS Table1ID really helped!

Answer (score 0):

In `GridView` control you can have a `TemplateField` containing `Hyperlink` (see the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/225414/Hyperlinked-Image-in-ASP-NET-GridView) to my article for details of this solution).

Also, it might be less labor-intensive if you use `SqlDataSource` assigning your select statement to its property and passing it to `GridView.DataSource` property. It will take just several lines of code and do the job for you. Regards, AB

Comment: Hmm not sure exactly how to use the GridView.DataSource in this case. Also, I should add that I do paging on this gridview so I put everything into a DataTable then I do DataBind()